# JQuery element missing detach() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

The detach() method is surprising lost from the object, when i assign it to a variable.

```
//assign element to a variable
top = $("#context-menu");

// top.detach is undefined
top.detach();

//this works
$("#context-menu").detach();
```

How is it even possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) is a built-in window attribute meaning the top parent of the window - used for example in framesets.

I suggest you use `var $top=...` instead

> Note: Starting in Gecko 6.0, this property is correctly read only.